# Uniqueness of Cholesky Decomposition

Tags: matrices

Suppose A=LL<sup>T</sup>, where L is a lower triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are all positive. If another lower triangular matrix P also satisfies A=PP<sup>T</sup>, and the diagonal entries of P are also positive, show that P=L.

This are my steps.

LL<sup>T</sup> = PP<sup>T</sup>

L=PP<sup>T</sup>L<sup>-T</sup>

P<sup>-1</sup>L=(L<sup>-1</sup>P)<sup>T</sup>=D where D is a diagonal matrix.

 L=DP

But I am stuck after this. I have not used the property that the diagonal entries of L and P are positive. Does this imply that D=I?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello there. We encourage users to type math expressions using MathJax, so it would be better if you take some time to read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

$$P^{-1}L=D$$

$$L=PD$$

Hence substitute that into $LL^T=PP^T$,

$PDD^TP^T=PP^T$, we have $D^2=I$.

Now use the positivity of the diagonal entry to conclude that $D=I$.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out my mistake.